# GLSL PointSprite for particle system

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, particle-system, point-sprites

I'm using an ParticleSystem with PointSprites (inspired by the Cocos2D Source). But I wonder how to rebuild the functionality for OpenGL ES 2.0

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glEnableClientState(GL_POINT_SIZE_ARRAY_OES);
glPointSizePointerOES(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(PointSprite),(GLvoid*) (sizeof(GL_FLOAT)*2));
glDisableClientState(GL_POINT_SIZE_ARRAY_OES);
glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
```

these generate BAD_ACCESS when using an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
Should I simply go with 2 TRIANGLES per PointSprite? But thats probably not very efficent (overhead for extra vertexes).

EDIT:
So, my new problem with the suggested solution from:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/opengl-es-2-0-point-sprites-size/15528#15528

is a possibility to pass many different sizes in an batch call. I thought of using an Attribute instead of an Uniform, but then I would need to pass always an PointSize to my shaders - even if I'm not drawing GL_POINTS. So, maybe a second shader (a shader only for GL_POINTS)?! I'm not aware of the overhead for switching shaders every frame in the draw routine (because if the particle system is used, I want naturally also render regular GL_TRIANGLES without an pointSize)... Any ideas on this?

Comment: This should be what you're looking for:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/opengl-es-2-0-point-sprites-size/15528#15528

Comment: Thank you! That link is very useful. So, my only problem with this solution is a possibility to do something similiar like "glPointSizePointerOES" on GLSL (on the link its suggested to use an uniform for the point size - so many different points with different sizes are not drawable in a batch call with glDrawArrays). I thought of using an Attribute instead of an Uniform, but then I would need to pass always an PointSize to my shaders - even if I'm not drawing GL_POINTS. So, maybe a second shader (a shader only for GL_POINTS)?! Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So doing the thing here as I already commented here is what you need: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/opengl-es-2-0-point-sprites-size/15528#15528

And for which approach to go, I can either tell you to use different shaders for different types of drawables in your application or just another boolean uniform in your shader and enable and disable changing the `gl_PointSize` through your shader code. It's usually up to you. What you need to keep in mind is changing the shader program is one of the most time costly operations so doing the drawing of same type of objects in a batch will be better in that case. I'm not really sure if using an if statement in your shader code will give a huge performance impact.